# Display Image from URL

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyside, pyside6

I am trying to display an image from a URL in pyside6, but can't get anything to work.

```
def getIcon(data):
    iconID = data['weather'][0]['icon']
    icon = QPixmap("http://openweathermap.org/img/w/" + iconID + ".png");
    return icon
```

And

```
self.temperatureIcon = QtWidgets.QLabel(self).setPixmap(getIcon(self.weatherData))
```

is the code I have.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

QPixmap does not download the image from a url so you must download it for example using QNetworkAccessManager:

```py
import sys
from functools import cached_property

from PySide6.QtCore import Signal, QObject, Qt, QUrl
from PySide6.QtGui import QImage, QPixmap
from PySide6.QtNetwork import QNetworkAccessManager, QNetworkReply, QNetworkRequest
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QGridLayout,
    QLabel,
    QLineEdit,
    QPushButton,
    QWidget,
)


class ImageDownloader(QObject):
    finished = Signal(QImage)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.manager.finished.connect(self.handle_finished)

    @cached_property
    def manager(self):
        return QNetworkAccessManager()

    def start_download(self, url):
        self.manager.get(QNetworkRequest(url))

    def handle_finished(self, reply):
        if reply.error() != QNetworkReply.NoError:
            print("error: ", reply.errorString())
            return
        image = QImage()
        image.loadFromData(reply.readAll())
        self.finished.emit(image)


class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.lineedit = QLineEdit()
        self.button = QPushButton("Start")
        self.label = QLabel(alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)

        lay = QGridLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.lineedit, 0, 0)
        lay.addWidget(self.button, 0, 1)
        lay.addWidget(self.label, 1, 0, 1, 2)

        self.downloader = ImageDownloader()

        self.downloader.finished.connect(self.handle_finished)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.handle_clicked)

        self.lineedit.setText("http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/01d@2x.png")

        self.resize(640, 480)

    def handle_finished(self, image):
        pixmap = QPixmap.fromImage(image)
        self.label.setPixmap(pixmap)

    def handle_clicked(self):
        url = QUrl.fromUserInput(self.lineedit.text())
        self.downloader.start_download(url)


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 3):

***Here's another simple solution\example:***

```py
import sys
import requests
from PySide6.QtGui     import QPixmap, QScreen
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLabel


URL = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/7/7d/Lenna_(test_image).png'


class App(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()
 
    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle('getAndSetImageFromURL()')
        self.label  = QLabel(self)
        self.pixmap = QPixmap()
        self.getAndSetImageFromURL(URL)
        self.resize(self.pixmap.width(),self.pixmap.height())
        screenSize = QScreen.availableGeometry(QApplication.primaryScreen())
        frmX = (screenSize.width () - self.width ())/2
        frmY = (screenSize.height() - self.height())/2
        self.move(frmX, frmY)
        self.show() 
    
    def getAndSetImageFromURL(self,imageURL):
        request = requests.get(imageURL)
        self.pixmap.loadFromData(request.content)
        self.label.setPixmap(self.pixmap)
        #QApplication.processEvents() # uncoment if executed on loop
    
      
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    gui = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

| which outputs: |
| --- |
| [image] |

Answer (score 1):

```
import sys
import requests

import PySide6
from PySide6.QtNetwork import QNetworkAccessManager, QNetworkRequest, QNetworkReply
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QTableView, QWidget, QApplication, QGridLayout, QHeaderView
from PySide6.QtCore import Qt, QAbstractTableModel, QObject, Signal, QUrl
from PySide6.QtGui import QColor, QIcon, QPixmap, QImage

from datetime import datetime

    class MagicIcon():
        def __init__(self, link):
            self.link = link
            self.icon = QIcon()
            try:
                response = requests.get(self.link)
                pixmap = QPixmap()
                pixmap.loadFromData(response.content)
                self.icon = QIcon(pixmap)
            except:
                pass

    
    class MainWindow(QWidget):
        def __init__():
            super().__init__()
            self.setWindowIcon(MagicIcon(
                    "https://img.icons8.com/external-flatarticons-blue-flatarticons/65/000000/external-analysis-digital-marketing-flatarticons-blue-flatarticons-1.png"
            ).icon)
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        wid = MainWindow()
        wid.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Use `requests` module to fetch image and store them.